# how I can generate Properly html tag with javaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I Create this code for replace something and show a button :

```
var text = $(item).html().replace(exp, "<button onclick='alert('hi')' id='btnac' href='$1' >Click</button>");
```

But in page I get this and I cant show alert on any function :

```
<button onclick="alert(" hi')'="" id="btnac" href="www.example.com">Click</button>
```

Comment: Your quotation marks are totally messed up - you will not make this work without escaping some of them...

Comment: Imagine what would happen if you put `<button onclick='alert('hi')' id='btnac'>` directly in your HTML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var text = $(item).html().replace(exp, "<button onclick='alert(\"hi\")' id='btnac' href='$1' >Click</button>");
```

You've got nested single quotes without escaping them.

Comment: Can you **please** explain your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Attach the click handler afterwards. You should also change your id to a class, because you are likely going to have multiple buttons the way you are doing this.

```
var text = $(item).html().replace(exp, "<button class='btnac' href='$1' >Click</button>");
$('.btnac').on( 'click', function() {
  window.alert( "hi!" );
} );
```